# How to print out values from two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

In my code i'm retriving marks from two tables ,everything is working properly except that when i want to print out value of the marks only marks values from one table are printed out. My question is there a way i can print out the marks values from  my both tables .( when I run the query directly in mysql it prints out marks values from both table but when i run the query through php I am only able to print out value for  marks from one table)

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$dbname="schoolreport";

$dsn="mysql:host=".$host."; dbname=".$dbname;
$pdo=new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);


$query="SELECT`mathematics`.`marks`,`science`.`marks` FROM
 `mathematics`, `science` WHERE `mathematics`.`userid`=`science`.`userid` AND
  `mathematics`.`term`='mid1' AND `science`.`term`='opener1'";
$stmt=$pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([]);

while($row=$stmt->fetch())
{
  echo $row['marks'];
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Having a table per subject is not the best database design.  Having 1 table with the marks with a foreign key to a subject table is much more flexible.

Comment: okay thanks, but just a quick question ,having  10 tables with 100,000 rows each or having a single table with 1,000,000  rows , would there be a perfomance difference?

Comment: If you have the correct indexes, not much.

Comment: Yep. Fix your schema.

Answer (score -1):

Add **aliases** to your fields and use them:

```
$query = "SELECT
        `mathematics`.`marks` as math_marks,`science`.`marks` as science_marks
    FROM
        `mathematics`, `science` 
    WHERE 
        `mathematics`.`userid`=`science`.`userid` 
        AND
        `mathematics`.`term`='mid1' 
        AND 
        `science`.`term`='opener1'";


// Later:
while($row=$stmt->fetch())
{
  echo $row['math_marks'] . ' - ' . $row['science_marks'];
  echo '<br>';
}
```